Как в Notepad++ заменить часть строки на строку с номером линии?
Есть файл
text_flow
text_flow
text_flow
text_flow

Нужно заменить конец строк на номер линии на которой находится текст
text_flow1
text_flow2
text_flow3
text_flow4

Как это сделать в notepad или sublime?

Отличный вопрос про Notepad++, не надо закрывать

В notepad++ можно добавить цифры по порядку. Имеем текст
text_flow
text_flow
text_flow
text_flow

Выделяем столбец, куда нужно вставить цифры


жмем Alt+c, выбираем Числа для вставки, начальное значение и шаг, кнопка Ок


